# Trying to make a small web scraper and I am getting this error

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromstring'
```

I am following along with an article which I am copying pretty much code for code with different site. I do not understand the error nor how to diagnose it. Looked up the error but haven't gotten any answers. Figure it may be a compatibility issue or small bug I cannot see.

```
# Web Scraper
import html
import requests

xp = '//*[@id="cont"]/pre[2]'

page = requests.get('https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/s/stevie_ray_vaughan/texas_flood_ver2_tab.htm')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Comment: The package lxml has to be installed and it has dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you meant `from lxml import html` instead of `import html`.

Comment: I replace it and I get "ImportError: No module named 'lxml'"

Comment: What site/article are you looking at?  Are you using Python 3?  What OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

[`fromstring`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html-fragments) is a method from [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) lib and is used this

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
```

To check if you have `lxml` installed in your environment try this command:

```
python -c "import lxml"
```

If you receive some error, you need to install the lib this way:

```
pip install lxml
```

Disclaimer: You may need sudo privileges to install it.